# Different account with different display resolution

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, resolution

I am having two accounts on my Macbook Pro with Retina display. My wife doesn't like my current resolution, so she changes to a larger one. However when I switch back to my account, the OS doesn't switch the display resolution, if I change to my preference, it also affects her account.

Is there any way to make it work?

Comment: are both accounts admins?

Comment: No, my wife's account doesn't have admin permission.

Comment: So she uses a Guest account!

Comment: I would set her up as admin and see if display preferences get saved then. The Guest account does not do that.